# How can I use ionic storage with capacitor?

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I am developing an android app using ionic, and instead of cordova I am using capacitor. When I try to run `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage` command, it gives me warning **[WARN] About to integrate your app with Cordova. Are you sure you want to continue?**. Please refer the warning image.

[image: warning image]

I am not sure, should I press yes or no. I want to use capacitor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should continue to use the Cordova plugin. The problem is how you're adding it. Don't use the `ionic cordova` CLI command (as in don't ever use it in a Capacitor app). Instead, use `npm install cordova-sqlite-storage` and then update your Capacitor platform with `npx cap sync` or `ionic cap sync`.

Comment: Will it do the same job what `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage` is doing?

Comment: no, that command is for cordova, since you are not using cordova don't use that command, run npm install as Alex told you

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to use [capacitor-sqlite](https://github.com/jepiqueau/capacitor-sqlite) plugin for your application.

`npm install --save capacitor-sqlite@latest`

[Here](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/community/plugins/) you can see the list of plugins that are available with a capacitor.

[Capacitor Community Plugins](https://github.com/capacitor-community)

If you don't have complex queries in your application and simple storage only then you can use [storage API](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/storage/).

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks Santosh, and can I then continue with https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/storage from `npm install --save @ionic/storage` onwards?

Comment: Yes you can use them and check the guideline documents for same

Comment: `capacitor-sqlite`  does the same job as `cordova-sqlite-storage`? Can I expect `sqlite` will be chosen to store data when I use the app in android?

Comment: Capacitor SQlite Plugin is a custom Native Capacitor plugin to create SQLite databases, tables, indexes and store permanently data to it.

Comment: Does `capacitor-sqlite` have any relationship with `@ionic/storage`? It was super easy to use `@ionic/storage`. At the same time it was choosing by default sqlite in android.

Comment: As per ionic storage documentation, storage  API is not meant for high-performance data storage applications. Take a look at using SQLite or a separate data engine if your application will store a lot of items, have high read/write load, or require complex querying.

Comment: Please check the link https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/storage/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212049/discussion-between-ratikanta-and-santosh-shinde).